# How to save the difference between the two rows while saving it in the same data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, diff, tidyverse

I would like to compute the difference of each row of `Variable X` and save it as a separate `Variable Diff` in the same `data.frame`. I know its going to give me the dimension error- I want the first row of `Diff` be left `blank` and have the rest of values beneath the `blank` row under `Diff`

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1500)
DF <- data.frame(A = runif(10,5,20), X = runif(10,100,200))
DF$Diff <- diff(DF$X)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `diff` returns a length 1 less than the original vector or column.  So, we need to append a value at the beginning or end.  It may be better to use `NA` instead of `""` as the `""` is a string and it would convert the whole vector or column to character class as there is a precedence for `character` over `numeric` and `vector`s can hold a single class

```
DF$Diff <- c(NA, diff(DF$X))
DF
#           A        X       Diff
#1  14.359319 120.6950         NA
#2  19.583288 189.0378  68.342790
#3  14.900511 151.1096 -37.928137
#4  10.134497 142.9174  -8.192231
#5   9.658943 121.5167 -21.400654
#6   8.878611 105.0224 -16.494314
#7  10.945591 170.9850  65.962624
#8  19.444123 167.2761  -3.708932
#9  19.240343 172.9342   5.658118
#10 17.199167 151.3785 -21.555779
```